# How to find the derivatives from Solve after obtaining 6 complex solutions?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I have a 3x3 matrix. By setting the determinant to 0, I find the values of w in terms of ka and graphed the complex solutions. m, M, k, l are constants:

```
mat = {{m*w^2 - 2*k, k, k*Exp[-3 I*ka]}, {k, M*w^2 - (l + k), 
    l}, {-k*Exp[-3 I*ka], l, M*w^2 - (k - l)}};
mydet = ExpToTrig[Det[mat]]
sol = Solve[mydet == 0, w]
funcs = w /. sol
ReImPlot[funcs, {ka, 0, Pi}, PlotLabel -> "w(ka)", PlotLegends -> {{"w1", "w2", "w3" ,"w4", "w5" ,"w6"}, "ReIm"}, ReImLabels -> {"Re", "Im"}, Frame -> True}
```

[image]
I need to find the derivatives of all 6 complex solutions with respect to ka to find the density of states. I thought that I needed to rewrite the solutions in an array, but that did not work when I tried it.

Comment: Can you include your definition of `mydet`? If you don't, people can't easily test the solution they propose. If it is complicated, you could invent a simpler matrix that has the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I added it :)

Comment: Do you expect your matrix to be Hermitian?  If so, it looks like you have a sign error on element (3,1)

Comment: What did you try? What kind of error did you get? I didn't check the answer but `D[funcs,ka]` returned an expression different from `funcs` for me.

Comment: @Melav can you provide the values you used for the constants, please

Comment: No, the matrix is correct since the graph of the solutions for w(ka) came out as expected. 
For the derivative I have tried `dkdw = D[funcs, ka]; dNdw = n/Pi * dkdw` to which I get a solution, but now I am unable to plot it. I tried `ReImPlot[dNdw, {ka, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotLabel -> "Density of States ", 
 PlotLegends -> {{"dN/d\[Omega]1", "dN/d\[Omega]2", "dN/d\[Omega]3", 
    "dN/d\[Omega]4", "dN/d\[Omega]5", "dN/d\[Omega]6"}, "ReIm"}, 
 ReImLabels -> {"Re", "Im"}, Frame -> True]` for my plot.
The constants are: k = 9; l = 12; m = 2; M = 4;

Comment: What is `n` in your `dNdw` definition? If you assign to `n` particular value you can plot with e.g. `ReImPlot[Evaluate[dNdw /. n->1], {ka, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotLabel -> "Density of States ", PlotLegends -> {{"dN/d\[Omega]1", "dN/d\[Omega]2", "dN/d\[Omega]3", "dN/d\[Omega]4", "dN/d\[Omega]5", "dN/d\[Omega]6"}, "ReIm"}, ReImLabels -> {"Re", "Im"}, Frame -> True]`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get both graphs, however I want only the positive complex solutions. How can I extract the positive solutions of funcs? Not just the real and positive, but the complex positive. So anything in the positive region of the plot.